# How to show the absense of logs in Loki with LogQL?

Tags: grafana, grafana-loki, logql

The picture shows the log activity of a system, produced by following `LogQL` query:

`sum(count_over_time({job="ET10"} |= "Station 1" [1m]))`

When the system is not running (due to a failure), it does unfortunately not produce a appropriate log line, but of course it stops log activity.

[image]

How can I show that a system is not running, by querying for "missing" logs?

First I tried to see the activity as bool:

`sum(count_over_time({job="ET10"} |= "Station 1" [1m])) > bool 0`

[image]

And then I tried to negate it:

`sum(count_over_time({job="ET10"} |= "Station 1" [1m])) < bool 1`

It does not work as expected, because I get no response for the time after approx. 2:30, because there are no logs.
I just get a response within the logging time, e.g. between the green bars, which is not what I want.

I want something like this:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for this, it really helped! You should add and accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution:

`absent_over_time({job="ET10"} |= "Station 1" [5m])`

[image]